# MSDN 2003 - How to display the full path of files

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++-6, msdn

We are moving from Microsoft [Visual Studio 6.0](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_Studio#Visual_Studio_6.0_.281998.29) to Microsoft [Visual Studio .NET 2003](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_Studio#Visual_Studio_.NET_2003).

In Visual Studio 6.0, the location of the file will be displayed if you go to the workspace, go to the FileView tab, right click on any file and select Properties. The full path of the file is displayed under File name.

However, in 2003, the file path is not displayed if I right click on a file and select Properties.

Is there any way I can view the path of the file from the workspace at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure the properties window is visible (View, Properties Window). Select a file in the Solution Explorer window, the properties window will show the full path.

Or, if you open the file then the full path is displayed as a tooltip when you mouseover the document's tab.

Answer (score 1):

In [Visual Studio 2008](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_Studio#Visual_Studio_2008) (and I suppose [Visual Studio 2003](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_Studio#Visual_Studio_.NET_2003)), the full path is conveniently displayed in the Properties section under "Full Path" - right click the file name in the Solution Explorer pane, then select Properties.

I have no clue what MSDN 2003 is, so you're kind of on your own there...

Comment: Thank you. I hope that our company upgrades to VS 2008 soon!

Answer (score 0):

It seems the only way is to open the file in question, then do File -> Save As. The path will then be displayed in an Windows Explorer style window.

Not very intuitive, but it is the only way I can find.

Answer (score 0):

If focus is in a code editing window should should be able to do `File`, `Advanced Save Options` (or use the shortcut `Ctrl+f, v`). Here you should see the full path of the file which can be highlighted and copied.

Comment: Unfortunately, advanced save options does not show the path of the file either. It only has 2 sections: Encoding and Line Endings.

I am using MSDN version 7.1.6030.